# How can we identify wether the client is viewing my website from a mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, cs50

wondering if any of you could help me out...

My issue is that I need to adjust the size of an image and rearrange the positions of elements in HTML depending on wether the client is using a phone or a larger screen such as a laptop.

I need a function which can detect if the user is viewing my website using a mobile or a desktop.

I searched the internet and found **very very long** solutions to them and I feel there should be a shorter one.

I am using `django` (python) for my server and `HTML`, `CSS` and `JAVASCRIPT` for the front end.

If anyone could provide me a function to do so, I would be very thankful to you.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you're specifically looking to solve in JavaScript, but you can very simply manage this with CSS using @media rules.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /*put your dynamic CSS here e.g. image size and rearrange flex/grid to change 
  the element order*/
}
```

This might be helpful: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use below `javascript` for detect user's `Device`

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
        var element = document.getElementById('text');
        if (isMobile) {
            element.innerHTML = "You are using Mobile";
        } else {
            element.innerHTML = "You are using Desktop";
        }
    </script>
```

**OR**

You can use `@Media` rules in `CSS` like below

```
/* On screens that are 992px or less, set the css*/
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .imag-class{
    /* your css for responsive image ex.*/
    height:100px;
    width :100px;
  }
}

/* On screens that are 600px or less, set css */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .imag-class{
   /* your css for responsive image*/
   height:50px;
   width :50px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a note, this particular area is filled with land mines. I would highly recommend using a CSS framework like Bootstrap or Tailwind if you’re just getting started.

Comment: Yes i am agree with @FlipperPA , if you want to use for only displaying image as per Device then CSS is the best solution